# How do I use LVM with 12.10 when I already have Windows 8?

Tags: 12.10, lvm, windows-8

I asked about the best way to setup a PC with Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 [here](https://superuser.com/questions/488636/setting-up-a-triple-boot-from-scratch-win7-win8-and-ubuntu) and followed the recommended order. But when I try to install Ubuntu 12.10 it doesn't allow me to select LVM without blowing away the Windows 8 installation. If I select the advanced option I can't create another partition (there's room on the drive). Is WUBI the only option? Or do I need to setup the partition before running the Ubuntu installer?

(Not sure how to get screenshots from the installer)

Comment: You can't have more than 4 partitions at any given time unless you're disk uses the GPT partition table.

Answer (score 1):

I would start out by doing all the partitioning from the Ubuntu live CD. Then install Windows 7 (using the existing partition scheme), add Windows 8, and finally add Ubuntu.

For Ubuntu I would create two partitions: /boot and LVM. Then follow the advice in [How to install ubuntu 12.10 with / partition on LVM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204546/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-10-with-partition-on-lvm) when you come to install Ubuntu.

The physical partitions will be Windows' two “system reserved” partitions plus /boot; the remaining partitions can (I hope) be logical partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't want to use the "Something Else" option in the installer, but I recommend you do.

I recommend using gparted to build your partitioning scheme the way you want it, and after that use the ubuntu installer option "something else" and appoint those partitions you created for specific mount points (/, /home, /boot, etc.; also: swap)

see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204546/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-10-with-partition-on-lvm)

The only difficulty here is that you'll need to make your own plan for the partitioning.

If you're using MBR/legacy mode, and both win7 and win8 need a "system-reserved" partition for booting, and if both windows's C: partitions must be primary, you have a problem. I don't know if grub's bootloader will be able to find a /boot partition on a lvm.
If win7 and win8 *can* both have their C: partition be logical, install them like that first:

- system-reserved partitions for win7 and win8: primary
- C: partitions for win7 and win8: logical

then ubuntu:

- /boot: primary
- /, /home, swap, etc.: logical

otherwise it won't work with MBR/legacy mode due to the limit of 4 (primary) partitions