# How to install ubuntu 12.10 with / partition on LVM?

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, boot-failure, lvm

After installing Ubuntu 12.10 I cannot boot my machine anymore. I get the following error.

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p6 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a system that has Windows 7 and Intel rapid start (win swap partition) on it. The hard disk is a fakeraid0, which is understood by the live cd.
I wanted a **dual boot**, so I had a primary /boot partition and *the rest of Ubuntu in a LVM*. Windows resides in two primary partitions (one 60GB for C: and one 350MB for booting Windows 7)

**How do I install ubuntu 12.10 in such a situation?** The 12.04 installer seemed to understand my intentions with the LVM and delivered a bootable system.
I cannot choose the "install on LVM" option, as this will destroy my already existing LVM with the win7 swap/hibernation partition. Instead, I chose "something else" and appointed existing partitions (/boot, /, /home, swap) to be used for installation.

**My partition scheme** is listed below, but bear in mind that this is backup information from when I had 12.04 installed. The scheme used for the 12.10 installation varies slightly, but it's *conceptually similar*.

```
Disk /dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0: 256.1 GB, 256066715648 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31131 cylinders, total 500130304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 32768 bytes / 65536 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe240c089

                              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p1   *   125831168   126547967      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p2       126547968   127062015      257024   83  Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p3            2048   125831167    62914560    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p4       127062016   500127743   186532864    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p5       483315712   500127743     8406016   84  OS/2 hidden C: drive
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p6       127064064   168024063    20480000   83  Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p7       466497536   483313663     8408064   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/mapper/isw_cjchifbged_Volume0p8       168026112   466495487   149234688   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

**What I tried in order to fix things was the following:**
Boot from live CD (actually: usb drive),
Mount /, /boot, /dev, /sys and /proc and chroot into that system (following [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation)),
`apt-get install lvm2` (which was *not* installed; following [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/256856/ubuntu-alert-dev-mapper-localhost-root-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell); `dpkg-reconfigure lvm2` is automatically triggered)

**This did not fix my problem.** When I inspected /dev/mapper from that shell (BusyBox built-in shell ash), it was empty.

Since I overwrote my previous Ubuntu 12.04 installation, there was no windows MBR, and thus the grub installer did not create a windows option. To make sure I could boot at least something, I ran the windows recovery tool `bootrec.exe /FixMbr`. Now I have a totally inaccessible zombie-ubuntu on my disk :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

I just tried again. The way I did it is first using gparted to create my partition scheme, and after that, I use the ubuntu installer and appoint the partitions I want to a specific mount points. Since this is exactly the way I did it the first time around, I don't know what made the installer change it's mind.

Important side-note: If you already have some version of Grub installed, and do not have the default windows MBR, the grub installer apparently does not detect your windows and thus it won't create a boot menu entry for it. So first restore your windows MBR. And eventually, don't forget to choose the right device (in my case a /dev/mapper/isw...Volume0) to write the mbr to.